# How to repeat cells in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I want to repeat cells in a pandas DataFrame.  I want to turn

```
name, number
a, 2
b, 1
```

into

```
name, number
a, 2
b, 2
a, 1
b, 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`np.tile` and `np.repeat`**

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        name=np.tile(df.name.values, 2),
        number=np.repeat(df.number.values, 2)
    ))

  name  number
0    a       2
1    b       2
2    a       1
3    b       1
```

---

**`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`**

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df.name.unique(), df.number.unique()]
    ).values.tolist(), columns=df.columns)

  name  number
0    a       2
1    b       2
2    a       1
3    b       1
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

repeating rows:

```
In [10]: pd.concat([df] * 2, ignore_index=True)
Out[10]:
  name  number
0    a       2
1    b       1
2    a       2
3    b       1
```

cartesian product of columns values:

```
In [14]: from itertools import product

In [15]: pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.name, df.number)), columns=df.columns)
Out[15]:
  name  number
0    a       2
1    a       1
2    b       2
3    b       1
```